# R: Add more beaty to a simple small plot

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have this `data.frame` which only contains 8 points.

```
Precision <- c(54.54, 60.0, 91.3, 95.23)
Recall <-c (0.02, 2.10, 0.18, 5.3)
dtable <- data.frame(Recall, Precision)
dtable
plot(dtable, type='o', col='blue', main='Precision / Recall Curve')
```

The problem is that when plotted it doesn't look nice at all.

[image]

I would like to, if possible, add more 'random' points to it, mark with a label each point of interest (say 'DL' label for the 1st point, SI for the 2nd, IR for the 3rd and IRR for the 4th) and maybe add more values to the x,y axis.

Also, would it be wise to normalize the values? And if so how?

Comment: scratch the normalization question i already found how to do it so...

Comment: Why in the world would you want to? Plot looks good to me. Unless by "add more 'random' points to it" you mean "jitter the points so they don't overlap so much" which would be reasonable here but probably isn't the best solution anyway.

Comment: i dunno what `jitter` exactly does even though i tried it

Comment: Jittering (and the R function of the same name) adds a small amount of random noise to the data, usually with the goal of making overlapped points more visible on a graph. That is, they look "jittery"

Comment: Well my points aren't overlapping, the contrary they are so few that the plot looks 'empty'. that is why i need to add some points in between the 4 I already have

Comment: That's completely unnecessary. What is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dear users, I appreciate the downvoting but I am more than happy to address your concern. I am simply trying to help the OP and throwing downvotes here and there without a reason will not move this along.**

> I would like to, if possible, add more 'random' points to it,

There are different kind of random distributions (e.g. Normal, Poisson, Binomial, etc.) and you'll need to specify that first before anyone can answer this question.

> mark with a label each point of interest (say 'DL' label for the 1st
>   point, SI for the 2nd, IR for the 3rd and IRR for the 4th)

Many ways, this is one of them:

```
Precision <- c(54.54, 60.0, 91.3, 95.23)
Recall <-c (0.02, 2.10, 0.18, 5.3)
myLabel <- c("DL", "SI", "IR", "IRR")
dtable <- data.frame(Recall, Precision)
plot(dtable, pch="", type="o", col='blue', main='Precision / Recall Curve')
text(Recall, Precision, myLabel)
```

Try a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=R+label+data+points) for other more sophisticated solutions.

> and maybe add more values to the x,y axis.

I am guessing you mean the min and max of the two axes? They scale with your data so you don't need to manually tweak them. But if you want a fixed axes min/max, you can use `xlim` and `ylim` options to do that. Check this [example](http://www.burns-stat.com/plot-ranges-of-data-in-r/).

Comment: It doesn't really work, I get some warnings and no text is added to the plot.

Comment: by adding more values to the axis, I meant to make the actual values of my 4 points to appear in both `x`,`y` axis.

Comment: @EnKei, I revised the code, the error message should be gone now.

Comment: "by adding more values to the axis, I meant to make the actual values of my 4 points to appear in both x,y axis." You can just concatenate x and y and then use label to show them. But it's a very unwise decision because the whole point of scatter plot is that we can use the location of the point to replace the actual numerical information. I will advise not to do that.

Comment: I agree that it would be helpful if people identified the reasons for the downvotes, so that you at least had the chance of improving your answer accordingly. Sometimes people will come back and say.

Comment: @Glen_b The reason for my downvote is that the initial answer, even though I provided a reproducible example, didn't worked. Even though I noted that, the user again provided code that does not work properly. I am also intrigued by the user's answer, redirecting me to Google Search. In general I have the feeling that the answer is really helpful but rather, a quick and sloppy one to capture the + points. Unless you are referring to the downvotes in my question.

Comment: @Enkei PenguinKnight's code runs perfectly on my machine

Comment: @EnKei, I tested all my code before posting. Even with the first "wrong" version, on my R it only shows an unrecognized option was used, the graph was still successfully produced. Also, the Google Search is not just taking you to Google, it takes you to a Google with a pre-defined search term and you can see the appropriate results right away. I can't list all possible R sites here because there are simply too many.